# Randomly combine two binary trees

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm working on a project about genetic algorithm, the gene is binary trees.

Now I need to recombine them, the method is to randomly select a node on the two trees, and then replace them.

For example:

Tree 1 and 2, select node C from 1 and node I from 2

```
   A           H
 B   C       I   J
D E F G     K L M N
```

After combination

```
   A
 B   I
D E K L
```

My node structure:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

My method to get random nodes, it will return a random node:

```
def getRandomNode(root):
        rootSize = treeCal.treeSize(root)
        leftSize = treeCal.treeSize(root.left) if root.left else 0
        rightSize = treeCal.treeSize(root.right) if root.right else 0
        if leftSize == rightSize == 0: 
            return root
        randNum = random.randint(1, rootSize)
        if randNum <= leftSize: 
            return treeCal.getRandomNode(root.left)
        elif randNum == leftSize + 1:
            return root
        else:
            return treeCal.getRandomNode(root.right)
```

The method I currently use, dad and mom are both the root of the tree, the first method will report an error (cannot assign to function call), the second method is useless:

```
def recombine(dad, mom):
        child = dad
        getRandomNode(child) = getRandomNode(mom)
        return child

def recombine(dad, mom):
        child = dad
        select = getRandomNode(child)
        select = getRandomNode(mom)
        return child
```

I have searched on Internet for a long time, but I can’t get the answer I want. Most of the answers are to insert the second tree into the end of the first tree, which does not meet my requirements.

Comment: You just want to replace the `element` right? Try `getRandomNode(child).element = getRandomNode(mom).element` as you don't want to replace the full node (in that case you will loose also connections with left and right) but just the content

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the two trees have the same shape? If not, what is the expected shape of the output tree?

Comment: In the given example the random nodes seem to always come from the same *level*. Moreover the result has nodes `A`, `B`, `D` and `E` at exactly the same place as in the first input tree. This would be very unlikely if it were random. Is there a rule you haven't mentioned, or is this all coincidence?

Comment: Should the returned tree be a *new* tree, leaving the original input tree in their original state, or can the input trees be mutated/destroyed at will?

Answer (score 2):

the function getRandomNode() will return a value which you're storing, the value inside the function gets replaced by the new value inside the function.
Note that you're not making a change in the tree in any way. You can modify the recombine function to change one of the children of the random node.

```
def recombine(dad, mom):
    child = dad
    select = getRandomNode(child)
    select2 = getRandomNode(mom)
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        select.right = select2
    else:
        select.left = select2
    return child
```